# invisible graphical output from python in neovim in alactritty on macos

Tags: python, macos, terminal

(As I'm not sure where to start and which details to include, I'll keep it short and add details as requested; I hope that works.)

When running python code in the neovim, visual output (like from `matplotlib`) seems to open a new app on my Mac, but I cannot see it or open these apps. Here they are in the bar (it's vertical and I deactivated the dot normally shown on the icons):

[image]

When I click either icon in the bar, or command-tab to one of them, the app "python" is activated, but there are no windows, and there are no items in the menu bar either:

[image]

What can I do to see these graphs?